# Clarification on function pointers in C

Tags: c

The following code comes from example [abo3.c](http://community.corest.com/~gera/InsecureProgramming/abo3.html) from [Insecure Programming](http://community.corest.com/~gera/InsecureProgramming) — see also [Why cast `extern puts` to a function pointer `(void(*)(char*))&puts`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051974):

```
int main(int argv,char **argc) {
    extern system,puts; 
    void (*fn)(char*)=(void(*)(char*))&system; // <==
    char buf[256];
    fn=(void(*)(char*))&puts;
    strcpy(buf,argc[1]);
    fn(argc[2]);
    exit(1);
}
```

Specifically this line:

```
void (*fn)(char*)=(void(*)(char*))&system;
```

I think that `void (*fn)(char*)` sounds like a lambda, but I know that it's not.
Then, maybe this is only a play with parentheses, where `void *fn(char*)` is a declaration of a function and this function is referencing `system`? But why does the `(char*`) parameter have no name? Is this permitted?

Comment: The line `extern system, puts;` worries me.  It declares that there are two externally defined integers (because there is no explicit type specified).  These declarations shadow the declarations in `<stdlib.h>` and `<stdio.h>`.  However, at link time, the functions will probably be used to satisfy the references.  Note that the `extern` line is invalid in C99 and beyond – and was dubious at best in pre-standard or C89/C90 standard C.

Comment: Your declaration `int main(int argv, char **argc)` is not technically invalid, but is 100% unorthodox.  The integer argument is usually called `argc` (argument count), and the `char` double-pointer is usually called `argv` (argument vector).  If you're going to use non-standard names, please do not, for everybody else's sanity, use the names reversed!

Comment: Use `int (*fn)(char const *)=&system;`, it's better to avoid casts.

Comment: @4566976: The cast is necessary as `system()` is `int(*)(const char*)`. The `&` unnecessary, however.

Comment: @alk The cast is not necessary if you have the correct function pointer. It's bad to cast a function to another. I know that `&` is unnecessary.

Comment: Removed `ansi` tag. Tag explicitly says not to use it.

Comment: @NightSkyCode Absolutely not. The questions have almost same title but the contents is completely different. Moreover closing as duplicate to a bad question (score -1) isn't a good thing. Closure as duplicate should point to where the good question & information is (that's why you shouldn't take the date into account when doing so; an older question can be worse than a newer one asking the same thing).

Comment: Refer to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/840504/1928852) for a good explanation on function pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void (*fn)(char*)=(void(*)(char*))&system;
```

That line takes the address of the mis-declared symbol `system` (should be `int(const char*)`, not implicit `int`), casts it to the type of `fn` and initializes that new local variable.
The type is `void(*)(char*)` or pointer to function receiving a single `char*` and returning nothing.

---

[Well, that code is all kinds of bad](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/27eee73310dea70f):

1. The traditional naming of the first two arguments to `main` is reversed:

   ```
   int main(int argv,char **argc)
   ```
2. Declaring the standard-library-functions `system` and `puts` using "implicit int" as `int`s. That's not even the wrong function-type, but a data-type!

   ```
   extern system,puts;
   ```
3. Casting the symbols address to a function-pointer is nearly sane. Now if only it was the right type... Anyway, on a box with data-pointers and code-pointers being the same size, it *probably* doesn't loose any information.

   ```
   void (*fn)(char*)=(void(*)(char*))&system; // <==
   fn=(void(*)(char*))&puts;
   ```
4. Checking whether `argv` [!] is at least 2 should really *not* be omitted here:

   ```
   strcpy(buf,argc[1]);
   ```
5. Calling a function through a function-pointer of wrong type is UB. Don't do that. Also, checking whether `argv`[!] is at least 3 before this point is *not* optional.
   fn(argc[2]);
6. Relying on implicit declaration for `strcpy` and `exit` is also really bad. Neither has a prototype consistent with that! (they don't return `int`)

Answer (score 8):

It declares the variable `fn` as a function pointer (to a function that has one argument of type `char *` and does not return anything (`void`).

This variable is initialised with the address of `system` - see http://linux.die.net/man/3/system. As noted from this page this will require the cast as given

Comment: Since `system()` returns `int` instead of `void`, is this UB?

Comment: @Kevin - Why do you think it is undefined behavior?

Comment: Because you cast the function into the wrong type.  It is *not* a `(void(*)(char*))`.  [The converse cast is illegal](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/01/19/60162.aspx), at least.

Comment: *address* of `system`, not value.

Comment: Oops - missed the `&` - That is not required. But then again the code is crap

Comment: In this case, the `&` is required, because `system` is declared as just `extern system`, which means `extern int system`.  So it will try to dereference `system` and grab an integer if you miss the `&`.

Answer (score 4):

> Then, maybe this is only a play with parentheses,where void *fn(char *) is a declaration of a function and this function is referencing system, i think

`void (*fn)(char *)`  is not a function , it is a function pointer. [You can refer here to learn about function pointers.](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/function-pointer-in-c/). And `()` do matter here you can't ignore them .

> But why the parameter (char*) have no name? this is permitted?

Yes ,it is allowed to do so . Its name is not that important but its **type** is.

Comment: `void *fn(char *)` does not define a function pointer. The function pointer definition is `void (*fn)(char *)`.

Comment: @alk  Actually it is what he asked in that line , he missed `()` which are present in question's code . I will make it more clear.

Answer (score 3):

It is pure and simple pointer to function, which is assigned address to the `system` call

Answer (score 2):

First you go to the trouble of declaring a function pointer to `system`.

Then you throw it all away by redefining it to point to `puts`.

Then it appears that you try to index an `int`, but you have reversed the usual naming convention for `main`, which is

```
int main (int argc, char **argv)
```

Comment: Sir `argc` is decalred as `char ** argc `. That may have been confusing.

Comment: How did someone end up with `argc` and `argv` being that way around?

Comment: @ameyCU well spotted, he has reversed the usual argument naming convention for `main`.

Comment: @Tommy It's a rookie mistake (a very rookie mistake)

Answer (score 1):

It is a pointer to Function. Let me show you if you try to make an application in C that will use text menus where instead of **switch** I will use pointer to Function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>

void clearScreen( const int x );
int exitMenu( void );
int mainMenu( void );
int updateSystem( void );
int installVlcFromPpa( void );
int installVlcFromSource( void );
int uninstallVLC( void );
int chooseOption( const int min, const int max );
void showMenu( const char *question, const char **options, int (**actions)( void ), const int length );
int installVLC( void );
int meniuVLC( void );
void startMenu( void );

int main( void ){
    startMenu();
    return 0;
}

void clearScreen( const int x ){
    int i = 0;
    for( ; i < x ; i++ ){
        printf( "\n" );
    }
}

int exitMenu( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf( "Exiting... Goodbye\n" );
    sleep( 1 );
    return 0;
}

int mainMenu( void ){
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf( "\t\t\tMain Manu\n" );
    return 0;
}

int updateSystem( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf( "System update...\n" );
    sleep( 1 );
    return 1;
}

int installVlcFromPpa( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf("Install VLC from PPA \n");
    sleep( 1 );
    return 0;
}

int installVlcFromSource( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf( "Install VLC from Source \n" );
    sleep( 1 );
    return 0;
}

int uninstallVLC( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    printf( "Uninstall VLC... \n" );
    sleep( 1 );
    return 1;
}

int chooseOption( const int min, const int max ){
    int option,check;
    char c;

    do{
        printf( "Choose an Option:\t" );

        if( scanf( "%d%c", &option, &c ) == 0 || c != '\n' ){
            while( ( check = getchar() ) != 0 && check != '\n' );
            printf( "\tThe option has to be between %d and %d\n\n", min, max );
        }else if( option < min || option > max ){
            printf( "\tThe option has to be between %d and %d\n\n", min, max );
        }else{
            break;
        }
    }while( 1 );

    return option;
}

void showMenu( const char *question, const char **options, int ( **actions )( void ), const int length) {
    int choose = 0;
    int repeat = 1;
    int i;
    int ( *act )( void );

    do {
        printf( "\n\t %s \n", question );

        for( i = 0 ; i < length ; i++ ) {
            printf( "%d. %s\n", (i+1), options[i] );
        }

        choose = chooseOption( 1,length );
        printf( " \n" );

        act = actions[ choose - 1 ];
        repeat = act();

        if( choose == 3 ){
            repeat = 0;
        }
    }while( repeat == 1 );
}

int installVLC( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    const char *question = "Installing VLC from:";
    const char *options[10] = { "PPA", "Source", "Back to VLC menu" };
    int ( *actions[] )( void ) = { installVlcFromPpa, installVlcFromSource, mainMenu };

    size_t len = sizeof(actions) / sizeof (actions[0]);
    showMenu( question, options, actions, (int)len );
    return 1;
}

int meniuVLC( void ) {
    clearScreen( 100 );
    const char *question = "VLC Options";
    const char *options[10] = { "Install VLC.", "Uninstall VLC.", "Back to Menu." };
    int ( *actions[] )( void ) = { installVLC, uninstallVLC, mainMenu };

    size_t len = sizeof(actions) / sizeof (actions[0]);
    showMenu( question, options, actions, (int)len );

    return 1;
}

void startMenu( void ){
    clearScreen( 100 );
    const char *question = "Choose a Menu:";
    const char *options[10] = { "Update system.", "Install VLC", "Quit" };
    int ( *actions[] )( void ) = { updateSystem, meniuVLC, exitMenu };

    size_t len = sizeof(actions) / sizeof (actions[0]);

    showMenu( question, options, actions, (int)len );
}
```

Compile it and try it.

Answer (score 1):

The line is declaring a variable of a function pointer that takes a parameter and returns nothing  (void), this is needed along with the typecast to the same function prototype as extern functions are similar in their type to a void* pointer, they are not early bound during compilation.